# Unable to set the status bar transparent

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, android-statusbar

I'm trying to have both the `NavigationBar` and the `StatusBar` as `transparent` and then use `windowInsets` to adapt my Views.

I'm now able to have a transparent `NavigationBar` that correctly applies `windowInsets`, but **I can't change the `StatusBar` color**. I've tried every combination I've found online, but the only one that is working is using `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS`, which cause the `windowInset` to return 0 for the `systemWindowInsetBottom` (and this isn't good because I'm using a `BottomAppBar`).

While **the `StatusBar` is solid white**, `windowInset.systemWindowInsetTop` return the right amount of pixels and the views are correctly layed out, but when I scroll the `RecyclerView` it disappears behind the `StatusBar`.

This is my current setup, I really need a different set of eyes to spot the bug.

**MainActivity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setWindowBehindSystemBars()
    colorizeStatusBar()
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

private fun setWindowBehindSystemBars() {
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
}

private fun colorizeStatusBar() {
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
    window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparent)
}
```

**Theme**

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- other attributes, all related to color -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**EDIT**:

I tried setting `android:windowBackground` to blue and when the application opens I can see the blue behind the StatusBar for a brief moment, so I think something is setting the color back to white after that.

Comment: 1) `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS` you don't need this one 2) `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS` don't need this one either 3) set the status bar color in the style just like the navigation bar color 4) setContentView first, then call `systemUiVisibility` 5) try using `systemUiVisibility` on your content view's root layout instead of the decorView. That's my set up and I have it exactly as you want it to be

Comment: @TimCastelijns tried, still solid white StatusBar, but at least I have less code to maintain.

Comment: what device are you testing on? What android version

Comment: Samsung S8 with Android P, Pixel 3a with Android P, emulator with Android Q and emulator with Android O.

Comment: @TimCastelijns this morning I tried it on a Nexus 5 with Android M and and emulator with Android L, still solid white status bar.

I tried setting android:windowBackground to blue and when the application opens I can see the blue behind the status bar for a brief moment, so I think something is setting the color back to white.

Comment: It was an extremely stupid call I wrote months back to recolorize the status bar, hidden in one of the components. Sorry wasting your time.